# How to make dependant object sizes and positions in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I apologize for the way of formulating my question and problem. I am a newbie so bear with me. Let's say that I have a one big circle (circle A), then I have multiple circles whose centres are on the edge of the circle A. Now I want to do the following: changing the size of the big circle (for example making it smaller), but I want the centres of small circles to stay connected on the edge and also get smaller proportionally. Is this possible? What am I looking for and how is it called?

Comment: Scale does this. But theres several ways your descrption might be interpretted. Bear in mind illustrator is a direct modeler. In otherwords you make the model. Not a indirect modeller where you describe intent and the system makes the model

Comment: Illustrator doesn't really offer any "dependancies" between objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to Scale these objects. There are several ways to do this.

Use the Scale Tool (keyboard shortcut S).

1. Select all the objects
2. Choose the Scale Tool (S)
3. option/ alt click the center of the larger circle or anywhere you want to set as the reference point (the point the objects will scale from)
4. In the dialog box enter a percentage in the Uniform box that you want to scale your objects. Either type in a percentage or the use up and down arrow keys on your keyboard to scale +/- 1 %. Shift  plus the up/down arrow will change the value at increments of 10

Alternate method is:

1. Select all your objects
2. Go to Object> Transform> Scale
3. The same dialog box will pop up.

In the dialog box if you check the "Preview" box you can see the changes as you make them and before you exit it.